# Почему ошибка в строке ( progress bar )

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            Document doc;
            try {

                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://сайт").maxBodySize(0).get();
                content = doc.select("елемент");

                titleList.clear();
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

                for (Element contents : content) {
                    titleList.add(contents.text());
                    progress = progress + 10;
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);


                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: я бы обновил идею на твоем месте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

метод `doInBackground` не имеет доступ к UI потоку. для того чтобы передать значения в UI поток, нужно используя метод `publishProgress()`, который передает значения в  `onProgressUpdate()`, который уже имеет доступ к UI потоку.

```js
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
      Document doc;
      try {

          doc = Jsoup.connect("https://сайт").maxBodySize(0).get();
          content = doc.select("елемент");

          titleList.clear();
         

          for (Element contents : content) {
              titleList.add(contents.text());
              progress = progress + 10;
              publishProgress(progress);
          }


      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
  }
  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Не получается применить метод publishProgress() ,я меняю местами его c doInBackground и получается ещё больше ошибок.(можете написать пример как внедрить его в мой код)

Comment: вы мой код скопировали и у Вас не заработало? или же вы только добавили  `publishProgress() ` в `doInBackground `

Comment: скопируй весь класс к себе

Comment: сейчас попробую спасибо

Comment: Вы просто лучший  работает идеально ))) СПАСИБО

Comment: @СВОЯРЕАЛЬНОСТЬ. Не за что) напротив ответа галочку поставьте)